# How to get socket.io object in 2 different files in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

In **first file** I have:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(process.env.IO_PORT);

io.on('connection', socket => {
        socket.on('user.go', data => {
            console.log('go');
     }
}
```

In **second file** I need to access `socket` object from callback. How can I export it and use it in another file. Code:

```
socket.emit(`add.message`, {
      sender
});
```

Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use socket-io-client to start a new connection

https://socket.io/docs/client-api/

like here

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io('http://localhost');
```

Comment: I do not need new connection. I need socket from existing connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can't export a specific `socket`, but you can make a `function` that will receive the `socket` as argument in other file/s

fileA

```
const io = require('socket.io')(process.env.IO_PORT);
const sendMessage = require('./fileB');

io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('user.go', data => {
    console.log('go');
    sendMessage(socket);
  });
});
```

fileB

```
module.exports = socket => socket.emit(`add.message`, 'hello');
```

Comment: I have a function match() which runs on user action and have a socket.emit in the end of this function. match() function is in File A. I have a socket in File B. How to access socket from file B in function in file A? I tried your solution, but socket is undefined.